# Breaking down large dataset into organized index

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas

I'm trying to create an indexed dictionary of `shape_id`'s from a dataset that I have (see below). I realize I could use loops (and tried to do so), but I have an intuition that there's a bulk way to do this in pandas that isn't as computationally expensive.

Possible solutions:
[groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html),
[str.findall](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.findall.html?highlight=match), [str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html)

The dictionary should be structured like so:

```
{shape_id: [shape_pt_sequence, [shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon]]}
```

Here's what code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

# readability assignments for shapes.csv
shapes = pd.read_csv('csv/shapes.csv')
shapes_shape_id = shapes['shape_id']
shapes_shape_id_index = list(set(shapes_shape_id))
shapes_shape_pt_sequence = shapes['shape_pt_sequence']
shapes_shape_pt_lat = shapes['shape_pt_lat']
shapes_shape_pt_lon = shapes['shape_pt_lon']

shapes_tuple = []

# add shape index to final dict
for i in range(len(shapes_shape_id_index)):
    shapes_tuple.append([shapes_shape_id_index[i]])

print(shapes_tuple)
```

Here's the [LINK](https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/90f2e4f7e1b06964b23d) to the `shapes.csv` Gist.

Here's an empty shape_id index:

```
[[20992], [20993], [20994], [20995], [20996], [20997], [20998], [20999], [21000], [21001], [21002], [21003], [21004], [21005], [21006], [21007], [21008], [21009], [21010], [21011], [21012], [21013], [21014], [21015], [21016], [21017], [21018], [21019], [21020], [21021], [21022], [21023], [21026], [21027], [21028], [21029], [21030], [21031], [21032], [21033], [21034], [21035], [21036], [21037], [21038], [21039], [21040], [21041], [21042], [21043], [21044], [21045], [21046], [21047], [21048], [21049], [21050], [21051], [21052], [21053], [21054], [21055], [21056], [21057], [21058], [21059], [21060], [21061], [21062], [21063], [21064], [21065], [21066], [21067], [21068], [21069], [21070], [21071], [21072], [21073], [21074], [21075], [21076], [21077], [21078], [21079], [21080], [21081], [21082], [21083], [21084], [21085], [21086], [21087], [21088], [21089], [20958], [20959], [20960], [20961], [20962], [20963], [20964], [20965], [20966], [20967], [20968], [20969], [20970], [20971], [20972], [20973], [20974], [20975], [20976], [20977], [20978], [20979], [20980], [20981], [20982], [20983], [20984], [20985], [20986], [20987], [20988], [20989], [20990], [20991]]
```

The `shapes.csv` looks like this:

```
shape_id,shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon,shape_pt_sequence,is_stop
20958,44.0577683,-123.0873313,1,0
20958,44.0577163,-123.087073,2,0
20958,44.0576286,-123.0867103,3,0
20958,44.0574258,-123.086641,4,0
20958,44.0571421,-123.0866518,5,0
20958,44.0568706,-123.086653,6,0
20958,44.0566161,-123.0867028,7,0
20958,44.0565641,-123.0869733,8,0
20958,44.0565503,-123.0872603,9,0
20958,44.0565536,-123.087631,10,0
20958,44.0565439,-123.0879283,11,0
20958,44.0564661,-123.087894,12,0
20958,44.0565124,-123.0881793,13,0
20958,44.0565181,-123.0884921,14,0
20958,44.0565331,-123.0888668,15,0
20958,44.0565406,-123.0892323,16,0
20958,44.0565406,-123.0896295,17,0
20958,44.0563515,-123.0897096,18,0
20958,44.056073,-123.0897108,19,0
20958,44.0558501,-123.0897,20,0
20958,44.0558358,-123.0897016,21,0
20958,44.0556489,-123.0896861,22,0
20958,44.0554398,-123.0896781,23,0
20958,44.0552033,-123.0896776,24,0
20958,44.0549253,-123.089692,25,0
20958,44.0546778,-123.0897281,26,0
20958,44.0546578,-123.0897326,27,0
20958,44.0546338,-123.0896965,28,0
20958,44.0543988,-123.0896838,29,0
20958,44.0543536,-123.0899543,30,0
20958,44.0543628,-123.0903496,31,0
20958,44.0543668,-123.0906733,32,0
20958,44.0543718,-123.0910178,33,0
```

In shapes.csv, for instance, `20958` has a max `shape_pt_sequence` value of 72. `20960` has a max `shape_pt_sequence` value of 400, etc.

Comment: What is the output you want? What is `stops.csv`? You didn't use it in your code.

Comment: Stops was a typo, should be shapes.csv. Corrected now. The output I am trying to get is in the form `[shape_id:[shape_pt_sequence, [shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon]]]`

Comment: Is the post tl;dr? I can slim it down a bit.

Comment: `[shape_id:[shape_pt_sequence, [shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon]]]` is not a valid Python structure, can you give some real example. And why you want this form, and you to use it. Something like this: `{20928:[[1, 2, 3, 4, ...], [[44.0577683, ...], [-123.0873313]]], 20960:...}`

Comment: Your data structure is redundant, because you can access a list of points by index, like `print data[20958]` giving `[(44.0577683,-123.0873313),(44.0577163,-123.087073),...]` and `print data[20958][1]` giving `(44.0577163,-123.087073)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need the sturct like `[shape_id:[shape_pt_sequence, [shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon]]]`, It's not very useful for data selection, you can use MultiIndex:

```
shapes = pd.read_csv('shapes.csv')
shapes.set_index(["shape_id", "shape_pt_sequence"], inplace=True)
```

Then to select all the data for 20958:

```
print shapes.loc[20958]
```

to select one point:

```
print shapes.loc[20958, 45]
```

select data for 20958 with shape_pt_sequence in range:

```
print print shapes.loc[(20958, slice(45, 48)), :]
```

select data with the shape_pt_sequence in [45, 48]:

```
print shapes.loc[(20958, [45, 48]), :]
```

If you really want the form, here is the code:

```
shapes = pd.read_csv('shapes.csv')

def f(df):
    return [df.shape_pt_sequence.tolist(), [df.shape_pt_lat.tolist(), df.shape_pt_lon.tolist()]]

res = shapes.groupby("shape_id").apply(f).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer variation. MultiIndex did the trick for me! I will also study indexing a little more now!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your REAL task is not validating the data file, reading the file and filling an appropriate data structure with a loop isn't bulky, not at all...

```
f = open('shapes.csv')
f.next() # skip headers
lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f] # f is closed automatically
data = {} ; item = 0
for i, lat, lon, seq, stop in lines:
    i = int(i)
    if i != item:
        item = i
        data[item] = [(float(lat), float(lon))]
    else:
        data[item].append((float(lat), float(lon)))
```

There is no need for a `stop` sentinel in your data file, and there is no need to explicitly store an index for each coordinate pair.